# I want my #OthersMain to have an overflow of visable But cant get it to work

Tags: html, css

OthersMain is displaying Overflow: hidden; i need it to be overflow: Visible;
Any help?

```css
body, html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Home.html */

#LeftMainSection {
 background-color:#FFA500;
 width: 180px;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-left: -180px;
 animation: LeftMove 1s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    border-right:10px solid black;
}
#LeftMainSection a {
 padding-top: 9px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 background-color:rgba(153, 99, 0, .6);
 width: 180px;
 height: auto;
    padding:10px;
 display: block;
    border-bottom:10px solid black;
    border-right:10px solid black;
}


@keyframes LeftMove {
 0% {
  margin-left: -180px;
 }
 100% {
  margin-left: 0;
 }
}
#BorderBottomBlack {
 border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
#BorderTopBlack {
 border-top: 10px solid black;
}
#RandomInfo {
 text-align: center;
}
#HomeMain, #OthersMain{
        text-align:center;
 overflow: visible;
 text-indent: 40px;
 color: white;
 height: 100%;
 background-color:#664200;
 margin-right: 245px;
 margin-left: -180px;
 animation: LeftMove 1s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#OthersMain{
 font-size:.8em;
    overflow:visible !important;
}
#TopHR, #BottomHR{
    border:solid black;
 height:10px;
    background-color:black;
}
#HomeMain p{
    font-size:1.3em;
    text-align:center;
 padding: 10px;
}
#AboutPG{
    font-size:1.3em;
 text-align:left;
    padding: 10px;
}
#Flip {
 transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
#RightMainSection {
 border-top: 10px solid black;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
    background-color:#FFA500;
 width: 250px;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
}
#News1, #News2, #News3, #News4 {
 background-color:#C27D00;
    border-left:10px solid black;
    border-bottom:10px solid black;
 height: 140px;
 width: 250px;
    
}
#itm1, #itm2, #itm3, #itm4{
    text-align:center;
 width:100%;
    height:121px;
    background-color:black;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#ShopLink1, #ShopLink2, #ShopLink3, #ShopLink4{
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:black;
}
#News4{
 height:150px;   
}
#News2 h1, #News3 h1, #News4 h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 font-size:.89em;
}

#News2, #News3, #News4 {
    font-size:1.1em;
 text-align:center;
}
#myProgress {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
}
#myBar {
 font-size: 10pt;
 width: 40%;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 30px;
 color: white;
}
#Percent, #pollsP {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
button {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 top: 112px;
}

#tezt{
 width:50%;
    height:10px;
}
#HomeMainDivTop {
 border-top: 10px solid black;
 width: 100%;
 height: 90px;
 background-color:#C27D00;
    border-bottom:10px solid black;
 text-align: center;
}
#Flip{
    margin-left:10px;
}
#LeftMain, #RightMain{
 height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#CatImg2{
      margin-right:10px;  
}
/* index.html */


#Indexh1{
    text-align:center;
 width:auto;
    height:50px;
}
#IndexA {
    display:inline-block;
 width:100%;
    height:100px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:gray;
}
video {
    background-color:black;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}


#ClickToHome{
    z-index:99;
    background:rgba(50, 50, 50, .5);
 width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Candidate/CSSFiles/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="LeftMainSection">
        <a id="BorderTopBlack" href="Index.html">Video</a>
        <a id="" href="Home.html">Home</a>
        <a id="" href="Bio.html">Bio</a>
        <a id="" href="Shop.html">Shop</a>
        <a id="" href="Campaign.html">About The Campaign</a>
        <a id="Others" href="Others.html">About The Other Candidates</a>
        <a id="" href="citations.html">Citations</a>
        <a id="BorderBottomBlack" href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
        <div id="RandomInfo">
            <h3>Random Info</h3> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <main id="OthersMain">
        <div id="HomeMainDivTop">
            <h2>About The Other Canidates</h2>
        </div>
        
        <div>

            <h1>Burton (Gus) Guster</h1>
            <hr id="">
            <h2 id="AboutPG">About "Gus"</h2>
            <p>Crime</p>
            <p></p>
            <p>Economy</p>
            <p></p>
            <p>Education</p>
            <p></p>
        
        </div>
        <div>
            <hr id="TopHR">
            <h1>Rickey</h1>
            <hr>
            <h2 id="AboutPG">About "Rickey"</h2>
            <p>Crime</p>
            <p></p>
            <p>Economy</p>
            <p></p>
            <p>Education</p>
            <p></p>
        
        </div>
        <div>
            <hr id="TopHR">
            <h1>Rick Grimes</h1>
            <hr>
            <h2 id="AboutPG">About "Rick Grimes"</h2>
            <p>Crime</p>
            <p></p>
            <p>Economy</p>
            <p></p>
            <p>Education</p>
            <p>sdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ih iuh uih iuh uih iu hui hiu </p>
        </div>
    </main>
    
    <div id="RightMainSection">
        <div id="News2"><h1>Campaign News</h1>This just in Burton Guster, Ricky, and Rick Grimes are found to be lying in the campaign just to get ahead in the polls that Puss In Boots swept away from them.</div>
        
        <div id="News3"><h1>World News</h1>Today in America Donald Trump is talking about visiting kim jong-un with Puss in Boots by his side.</div>
        
        <div id="News4"><h1>Local News</h1>Tomorrow Puss In Boots is planning to meet with local schools to find out what kids like most about school. And what teachers want to see changed for the childrens education.</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to have my Main with the id of #OthersMain to have an overflow of visible

I have tried to use the !Important add on to my css styles but still cant debug whats stopping it from being visible

Comment: try overflow: auto;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put: `overflow: scroll` or `auto` not visible and it will work also without `!important`

```css
body, html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Home.html */

#LeftMainSection {
 background-color:#FFA500;
 width: 180px;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-left: -180px;
 animation: LeftMove 1s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    border-right:10px solid black;
}
#LeftMainSection a {
 padding-top: 9px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 background-color:rgba(153, 99, 0, .6);
 width: 180px;
 height: auto;
    padding:10px;
 display: block;
    border-bottom:10px solid black;
    border-right:10px solid black;
}


@keyframes LeftMove {
 0% {
  margin-left: -180px;
 }
 100% {
  margin-left: 0;
 }
}
#BorderBottomBlack {
 border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
#BorderTopBlack {
 border-top: 10px solid black;
}
#RandomInfo {
 text-align: center;
}
#HomeMain, #OthersMain{
        text-align:center;
 overflow: auto;
 text-indent: 40px;
 color: white;
 height: 100%;
 background-color:#664200;
 margin-right: 245px;
 margin-left: -180px;
 animation: LeftMove 1s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#OthersMain{
 font-size:.8em;
    overflow:auto;
}
#TopHR, #BottomHR{
    border:solid black;
 height:10px;
    background-color:black;
}
#HomeMain p{
    font-size:1.3em;
    text-align:center;
 padding: 10px;
}
#AboutPG{
    font-size:1.3em;
 text-align:left;
    padding: 10px;
}
#Flip {
 transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
#RightMainSection {
 border-top: 10px solid black;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
    background-color:#FFA500;
 width: 250px;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
}
#News1, #News2, #News3, #News4 {
 background-color:#C27D00;
    border-left:10px solid black;
    border-bottom:10px solid black;
 height: 140px;
 width: 250px;
    
}
#itm1, #itm2, #itm3, #itm4{
    text-align:center;
 width:100%;
    height:121px;
    background-color:black;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#ShopLink1, #ShopLink2, #ShopLink3, #ShopLink4{
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:black;
}
#News4{
 height:150px;   
}
#News2 h1, #News3 h1, #News4 h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 font-size:.89em;
}

#News2, #News3, #News4 {
    font-size:1.1em;
 text-align:center;
}
#myProgress {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
}
#myBar {
 font-size: 10pt;
 width: 40%;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 30px;
 color: white;
}
#Percent, #pollsP {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
button {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 top: 112px;
}

#tezt{
 width:50%;
    height:10px;
}
#HomeMainDivTop {
 border-top: 10px solid black;
 width: 100%;
 height: 90px;
 background-color:#C27D00;
    border-bottom:10px solid black;
 text-align: center;
}
#Flip{
    margin-left:10px;
}
#LeftMain, #RightMain{
 height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#CatImg2{
      margin-right:10px;  
}
/* index.html */


#Indexh1{
    text-align:center;
 width:auto;
    height:50px;
}
#IndexA {
    display:inline-block;
 width:100%;
    height:100px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:gray;
}
video {
    background-color:black;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}


#ClickToHome{
    z-index:99;
    background:rgba(50, 50, 50, .5);
 width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Candidate/CSSFiles/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="LeftMainSection">
        <a id="BorderTopBlack" href="Index.html">Video</a>
        <a id="" href="Home.html">Home</a>
        <a id="" href="Bio.html">Bio</a>
        <a id="" href="Shop.html">Shop</a>
        <a id="" href="Campaign.html">About The Campaign</a>
        <a id="Others" href="Others.html">About The Other Candidates</a>
        <a id="" href="citations.html">Citations</a>
        <a id="BorderBottomBlack" href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
        <div id="RandomInfo">
            <h3>Random Info</h3> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <main id="OthersMain">
        <div id="HomeMainDivTop">
            <h2>About The Other Canidates</h2>
        </div>
        
        <div>

            <h1>Burton (Gus) Guster</h1>
            <hr id="">
            <h2 id="AboutPG">About "Gus"</h2>
            <p>Crime</p>
            <p></p>
            <p>Economy</p>
            <p></p>
            <p>Education</p>
            <p></p>
        
        </div>
        <div>
            <hr id="TopHR">
            <h1>Rickey</h1>
            <hr>
            <h2 id="AboutPG">About "Rickey"</h2>
            <p>Crime</p>
            <p></p>
            <p>Economy</p>
            <p></p>
            <p>Education</p>
            <p></p>
        
        </div>
        <div>
            <hr id="TopHR">
            <h1>Rick Grimes</h1>
            <hr>
            <h2 id="AboutPG">About "Rick Grimes"</h2>
            <p>Crime</p>
            <p></p>
            <p>Economy</p>
            <p></p>
            <p>Education</p>
            <p>sdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ihsdasdasd ad asd   ih uh uhu ih uihu hui hui hui hui hu ih iuh uih iuh uih iu hui hiu </p>
        </div>
    </main>
    
    <div id="RightMainSection">
        <div id="News2"><h1>Campaign News</h1>This just in Burton Guster, Ricky, and Rick Grimes are found to be lying in the campaign just to get ahead in the polls that Puss In Boots swept away from them.</div>
        
        <div id="News3"><h1>World News</h1>Today in America Donald Trump is talking about visiting kim jong-un with Puss in Boots by his side.</div>
        
        <div id="News4"><h1>Local News</h1>Tomorrow Puss In Boots is planning to meet with local schools to find out what kids like most about school. And what teachers want to see changed for the childrens education.</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```